# eureka service discovery client in different languages

Tags: php, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Is there a way to integrate the Netflix Service Discovery Server (Eureka) with different programming languages (e.g. php). 
For instance, we would like to make a service discovery client in php.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options:

1. Sidecar, if you're using spring cloud, there is [spring cloud netflix sidecar](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/tree/master/spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar) ([sample](https://github.com/spencergibb/oscon2015/tree/master/sidecar)) or if using netflix directly there is [prana](https://github.com/Netflix/Prana).
2. Eureka has an [http api](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations).

Comment: prana seems to be the best. I'll give it a try. Thank you very much

Comment: has anyone used this for PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/piwvh/php-eureka), which is a PHP client for Netflix Eureka service registration and discovery.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following:
.net - https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v2/discovery/netflix-eureka.html
nodejs - https://npm.io/package/eureka-js-client